# Maximum Z-Sum of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

Z-Sum(i,j) in a matrix M is defined as the sum of the elements in matrix M at positions (i, j), (i, j+1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j+1). Z-Sum(1,1) of the matrix shown in the figure is a11+a12+a21+a22.

[image]

Given a mXn matrix, value of i and j, write a python program to find the maximum Z-Sum in the matrix. Print the elements that form Z-structure in order that is print elements at positions (i, j), (i, j+1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j+1). And also print all the positions i,j of the matrix that corressponds to maximum Z-Sum. For example, given a 3X3 matrix as shown below:

1 2 3

2 4 7

1 2 3

The maximum z-sum is 16, the z-structures start with elements in position 1, 2 and 2, 2, the elements that is on the maximum z-structures are 2 3 4 7 and 4 7 2 3.

Input Format

First line contains the number of rows in the matrix m, r

Next line contains the number of columns in the matrix m, c

Next r lines contain the elements of the matrix, one line has the elements of one row and the elements in each column is separated by a space

Output Format

In the first line, print the maximum z sum

In the next 2*m lines, print the position of first element of Z-structure that has maximum z sum followed the elements in the Z-structure with maximum sum in the next line, where ‘m’ is the number of z-structures with maximum z sum

The position of first element of Z-structure with maximum sum and elements in the Z-structure with maximum sum has to be separated by a tab space. Print the elements in the Z-structure in such a way that Z shape is formed when traversed

Comment: You'll get a better response to your question if you show what research you've done, how you've attempted to solve the problem, and how your attempts have failed to give the desired results.

Comment: Also, this feels like a homework question you didn't even try to solve yourself. Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions before posting homework questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.